# assign values executed to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, assign

```
n = 1
for n in range(3):         
    p = Poly(a[n+1][0:3])
    print p 
    n=n+1
```

this is my coding. basically, I have a 3 times 3 matrix, I want to assign each row to a polynomial function and then assign each polynomial function to a new array. however, i do not know how to assign the value of p each time executed from the poly function to the array I want.

some body please help me.

the output of p executed looks like

- `(749.55*x**2) + (6.95*x**1) + (9.68*(10^-4)*x**0)`
- `(1285*x**2) + (7.051*x**1) + (7.375*(10^-4)*x**0)`
- `(1531*x**2) + (6.531*x**1) + (1.04*(10^-3)*x**0)`

basically, it will be good enough to build a 3*1 array from the executed p output.

for imformation , my matrix of a looks like this

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'PMIN', 'PMAX'], ['749.55', '6.95', '9.68*(10^-4)', '320', '800'], ['1285', '7.051', '7.375*(10^-4)', '300', '1200'], ['1531', '6.531', '1.04*(10^-3)', '275', '1100']]
[['A' 'B' 'C' 'PMIN' 'PMAX']
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]!  If you edit your question, select all your code, and click the button with `{}` and it will format it nicely as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = []
for n in range(3):
    p.append(Poly(a[n+1][0:3]))
print p
```

I don't have access to your `Poly` function or `a` array, but we can test it like this:

```
p = []
for n in range(3):
    p.append([n,n+1,n+2])
print p
#output:
#[[0, 1, 2],
# [1, 2, 3],
# [2, 3, 4]]
```

I also removed your lines with `n+1` and `n=n+1` because both of those are done automatically by using `n in range(3)` which does the following:

```
for n in range(3):
    print n
#output:
# 0
# 1
# 2
```

(note that it starts at `0` and ends with `2`, this is so that it runs exactly `3` times)

Comment: thanks, it solves my problem. can I ask one more question. of the value inside the output is in term of x. how could I differentiate the output against x for each term in the output?

Comment: That's different enough from the current question that you'd be better off posting a new question, asking how to take a derivative.  You'd need to post more details of that `Poly` function.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions describe this quite simply:

```
def Poly(a):
  return "{}x^2 + {}x + {}".format(a[0],a[1],a[2])
a = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'PMIN', 'PMAX'],[1,2,3,99,99],[4,5,6,42,42],[7,8,9,3.14,2.72]]
result = [Poly(a[n]) for n in range(1,4)]
print result
```

The output is:

```
['1x^2 + 2x + 3', '4x^2 + 5x + 6', '7x^2 + 8x + 9']
```

Answer (score 0):

> however, i do not know how to assign the value of p each time executed
>   from the poly function to the array I want.

```
results = []
for x in range(3):
   p = Poly(something)
   results.append(p) # adding it to the list `results`
```

By the way, in Python, there are no arrays, just lists (0-index collections) and dictionaries, which are more like hashes.

Comment: `try: import array except ImportError: CommentOnStackOverflow()`

Comment: If you've heard of arrays in python and are therefore confused by this statement, there _are_ arrays in `array` and `numpy`.